# Java: Retrieve and display value from database in label

Tags: java, crud

I am building a Java desktop app using Java Swing.

This is the select service method

```
public void select(int id){
        String sql = "SELECT num_of_working_days FROM working_days_and_hours WHERE id = ?";
        
         try {
            connection = SQLite_Connection.connect();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            
            preparedStatement.execute();
            preparedStatement.close();

            System.out.println("DB status 1: "+ preparedStatement.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

I would like to display the result of this in a label

```
    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jLabel1.setText(numberOfDays.select(1));     
        // numberOfDays.select(1);
        System.out.println("Entered: " + jTextField1.getText());
       
    }
```

There is an error at
       `jLabel1.setText(numberOfDays.select(1));`    
Saying 'void type not allowed here'.

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any input regarding this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Posted an updated answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your select method definition

```
public void select(int id)
```

This returns `void`

Looking at the Java doc `JLabel: setText(String str)`
This method requires a string DataType

Hence change ur method select to return a String i.e.

```
public String select(int id)
```

also in ur method Store the result from prepared statement like below

```
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();        // Get the result table from the q
    while (rs.next()) {               // Position the cursor to the result 
      String result = rs.getInt(1); //If ur Column is of int type
    }
preparedStatement.close();
return result;
```

Comment: Okay so then I'm getting an error that resultSet cannot be converted to String

Comment: @DinuliThalakumbura updated my answer, Let me know ifi tworked for you, in case ur column num_of_working_days is of type String please use rs.getString(1)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, 'void type not allowed here' so you should add return in your "select" method.

```
public String select(int id){
    String sql = "SELECT num_of_working_days FROM working_days_and_hours WHERE id = ?";
    
     try {
        connection = SQLite_Connection.connect();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        
        preparedStatement.execute();
        preparedStatement.close();

        return "DB status 1: "+ preparedStatement.toString();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
       return ex.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I came up with:

```
public ResultSet retrieveData(){
        String sql = "SELECT num_of_working_days FROM working_days_and_hours";
        try {
                connection = SQLite_Connection.connect();
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }finally {      
                      //Services.colsedConnections();
            }
        return resultSet;
    }
```